# 1/n + 1/(n+2) and Prime Pythagorean Triples

Tags: elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

I need help proving this conjecture:

Suppose you have two Natural Numbers, *n* and *m*, such that *n = m + 2*. Then *1/n + 1/m* is equal to some fraction which, when reduced, is equal to $\frac ab$ (for some *a*,*b* in the natural numbers) such that $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ for some *c* in the natural numbers.

Comment: I would first get rid of all references to $n$ by swapping it with $m+2$. Also note that if the fraction gives a Pythagorean triple when reduced, then it gives one when it's not reduced (albeit not a primitive triple).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n+2}=\frac{2n+2}{n(n+2)}$.
Note that actually you do not need to have a reduced fraction. If the numerator and the denominator have a common factor just cancel it when you want.

We can see that $a^2+b^2=(2n+2)^2+(n(n+2))^2=n^4+4n^3+8n^2+8n+4=(n^2+2n+2)^2=c^2$
This proves your conjecture.

Comment: Ahh I knew I was close. I got to the big 4th power polynomial but didn't even think I could actually factorize it. Thanks for the help.